# Call public property from partial class

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a public property in a partial class (`UserControl`) which I would like to access from another partial class (`Form`). However I cannot call this property, even though it is public. They are located in the same `namespace`, so this should not be the issue.

**Partial Class #1 (User Control)**

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    // This is the value I want to read from the main form
    public String MyVariableValue
    {
        get { return cboMyComboBox.Text; }
    }
}
```

**Partial Class #2 (Main Form)**

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    // This function should show a message box with the value
    private void ShowMyVariable()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You have selected: " + MyUserControl.MyVariableValue);
    }
}
```

**Error code:**

> CS0119 'MyForm' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

**Update:** I had a lot of errors in the original code which has been corrected. It is two *different* forms, that was not clear before, sorry...

Comment: You don't need to specify `MyForm` to access class member. When you specifiy class name the compiler will treat it as static member.

Comment: you could use `MyVariableValue` or `this.MyVariableValue`

Comment: That would only work if MyVariableValue were static.

Comment: @bradbury9 you seem to be on to something. However changing the property i Partial Class #1 isn't an option, since it cannot get its value from a combo box then...?

Comment: Seems like you are using the class name MyUserControl instead of the instance name of MyUserControl.

Comment: @Manish I believe you are right. Now I just need to find a way to transfer the instance name to my display method. Or finding an entirely different way of accesing the combo box selection from outside the user control...

Answer (score 2):

After the changes to your post, I suggest the following:
I assume the MyForm has an instance of the MyUserControl, which is necessary to show the usercontrol. Then you access the instance
Change

```
MessageBox.Show("You have selected: " + MyForm.MyVariableValue);
```

to

```
MessageBox.Show("You have selected: " + _myUserControl.MyVariableValue);
```

where _myUserControl is the name of the instance variable of type MyUserControl.
It is probably found in the other part of the MyForm class, the auto-generated part, and could look something like this:

```
MyUserControl _myUserControl = new MyUserControl();
this.Controls.Add(_myUserControl);
```

Comment: Sorry, there was an error in the original code. The property is in a different form than the method which needs to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Access it this modifier

```
 private void ShowMyVariable()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You have selected: " + this.MyVariableValue);
    }
```